# jQuery.data('itemname') not working but jQuery.attr('data-itemname') is working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is weird behavior but when I am trying to access some data attribute using jQuery data() function, it is returning me undefined but attr() is returning me the actual value. I know data works differently as it caches for the first time and then it retrieves from cache. I am using jQuery 1.4.2 and then tried looking with jQuery 1.7.1 and it did work. But I can't upgrade to 1.7.1 at the moment. Any thoughts on it??

I will appreciate any kind of suggestion or help provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HTML5 `data-*` objects being pulled into `.data` was not done until jQuery 1.4.3: http://api.jquery.com/data/#data-html5

Maybe you can  just update to 1.4.3?

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question: `data` doesn't work in jQuery 1.4.2. If you can't upgrade, you try [this plugin](http://binarykitten.com/js/288-html5-data-attributes-and-jquerys-data-pairing-made-in-heaven.html).

Comment: There is data function available in 1.4.2 so I thought it will be working. But when I read above mentioned comment, I figured out that it doesn't pull html5 data objects.

Comment: I'll just use attr. The only reason I asked this question was that I thought I may be doing something wrong and I didn't want to do something incorrectly.